# Appending the length of sentences to file

Tags: python, file, text, save, sentence

I found the length and index and i want save all of them to new file:

example:  index sentences length

my code

```
file = open("testing_for_tools.txt", "r")
lines_ = file.readlines()
for line in lines_:
    lenght=len(line)-1
    print(lenght)
for item in lines_:
    print(lines_.index(item)+1,item)
```

output:

```
64
18
31
31
23
36
21
9
1
1 i went to city center, and i bought xbox5 , and some other stuff

2 i will go to gym !

3 tomorrow i, sill start my diet!

4 i achive some and i need more ?

5 i lost lots of weights؟

6 i have to , g,o home,, then sleep  ؟

7 i have things to do )

8 i hope so

9 o
```

desired output and save to new file :

```
1 i went to city center, and i bought xbox5 , and some other stuff 64
2 i will go to gym ! 18
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using the following code. Note the use of `with ... as f` which means we don't have to worry about closing the file after using it. In addition, I've used f-strings (requires Python 3.6), and `enumerate` to get the line number and concatenate everything into one string, which is written to the output file.

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    lines_ = f.readlines()

with open("out.txt", "w") as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(lines_, start=1):
        line = line.strip()
        f.write(f"{i} {line} {len(line)}\n")
```

**Output:**

```
1 i went to city center, and i bought xbox5 , and some other stuff 64
2 i will go to gym ! 18
```

If you wanted to sort the lines based on length, you could just put the following line after the first `with` block:

```
lines_.sort(key=len)
```

This would then give output:

```
1 i will go to gym ! 18
2 i went to city center, and i bought xbox5 , and some other stuff 64
```